# LINQ to XML Get (children?) of element?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, unity-container

How would I go about getting the ID information using Linq. I'm trying to add them to an array of int.

```
  <FactionAttributes>
    <name>Player</name>
    <id>0</id>
    <relationModifier>1</relationModifier>
    <relations>
        <id0>100</id0>
        <id1>50</id1>
        <id2>50</id2>
        <id3>50</id3>
        <id4>50</id4>
        <id5>50</id5>
    </relations>
  </FactionAttributes>
```

That is my XML.

Here is the code I'm using so far.

```
    void InitFactions()
        {
            int count = 0;
            string filepath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/factiondata.xml";
            XDocument factionXML = XDocument.Load(filepath);

            var factionNames = from factionName in factionXML.Root.Elements("FactionAttributes")
                select new {
                    factionName_XML = (string)factionName.Element("name"),
                    factionID_XML = (int)factionName.Element("id"),
                    factionRelations_XML = factionName.Element("relations")// Need to turn this into array.
            };

            foreach ( var factionName in factionNames)
                ++count;

            foreach ( var factionName in factionNames)
            {
                Factions f = new Factions();            
                f.otherFactionsName = new string[count];
                f.otherFactionsRelation = new int[count];
                int others = 0;

                f.FactionName = factionName.factionName_XML;

                Debug.Log(factionName.factionRelations_XML);

                // Adds Rivals, not self to other list.
                foreach (var factionName2 in factionNames)
                {
                    if (factionName.factionID_XML == factionName2.factionID_XML)
                        continue;
                    f.otherFactionsName[(int)factionName2.factionID_XML] = factionName2.factionName_XML;

// THIS IS WHERE IM ADDING THE RELATIONS IN //
                    f.otherFactionsRelation[(int)factionName2.factionID_XML] = factionName.factionRelations_XML[(int)factionName2.factionID_XML];
                    Debug.Log(f.FactionName + " adds: " + factionName2.factionName_XML);
                    ++others;
                }
            }
        }
```

I have made multiple attempts using nodes and what not. I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: What is your expected output? 0,100,50,50,50,50,50 ?

Comment: Just trying to fill an array with the 100 50 50 50 50 50.

Comment: If you are happy the query is answered you should accept an answer by clicking a tick beside the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Path);

//To get <id>
var MyIds = doc.Element("FactionAttributes").Element("id").Value;

//To get <id0>, <id1>, etc.
var result = doc.Element("FactionAttributes")
                .Element("relations")
                .Elements()
                .Where(E => E.Name.ToString().Contains("id"))
                .Select(E => new { IdName = E.Name, Value = E.Value});
```

If you want array of ints replace the select with this

```
.Select(E => Convert.ToInt32(E.Value)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just after the relations Ids use this simple query

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\tmp\\test.xml");
var ids = doc.Descendants("relations").Elements().Select(x => x.Value);
```

If you want the Id and the relations ids in one array use this

```
var id = doc.Descendants("id").Select(x=>x.Value).Concat(doc.Descendants("relations").Elements().Select(x => x.Value));
```